# How can select last 7 max salaries from this table?

Tags: sql

```
NAME                        AGE     DEPTNO     SALARY
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
shasank                      25         11       2025
raju                         27         12       2027
bali                         31         10       2031
rambo                        32         11       2121
chir                         34         10       2123
son                          33         12       2131
don                          33         11       2132
ram                          28         13       2141
nag                          35         10       2213
dimpu                        33         12       2314
```

Comment: This question does not have enough context to be answerable.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` (or `TOP`) clauses?

Comment: Just saw your other questions. They are all just a table and title. Flagged.

Comment: looks like an assignment

Comment: Again, you don't mention what sql server you're using.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select top(7) *
from table
order by salary desc
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 7 salary FROM table1 GROUP BY salary
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT salary FROM table1 GROUP BY salary LIMIT 0,7
```